# PowerShell script to delete or archive older log files works fine locally but it didn't work on remote location

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am having an issue that I can't resolve. I am trying to create an script to delete or archive older log files. However, when I run my script on locally it's run well but it's didn't able to run on remote server. I am new to this, so I am not able to figure outs what went wrong. I simply copy my script and store  it locally on remote server and then try to run from there. After debugging script , I found that there is issue with "Get-Childitem" cmd as it's not able to find any file from a given location.

$Dir = Get-Childitem $path - Recurse

The above code didn't store anything in "Dir" on remote server but it's run fine locally.Can anyone help me what's wrong here.

Comment: What is `$Path`? This is probably because you can't access `$Path` from the remote server. Can you browse (using e.g. explorer) to the path comtents on the remote server?

Comment: Yes we can browse to the path and also confirm that there are some log files in that path too. I also think it's something's related to access but didn't able to identify exact cause.

Comment: Please add the content of the `$Path` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a command remotely, use the construction:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemotePC -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse}
```

Well, or describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: I think I'm not clear with my question. It's like that you devlop a ps script in your local env and everything is working fine. But when you copy the same script and store it into Remote Pc then Get-Childitem didn't return any files from given path.

Comment: Why copy a file to another environment when you can immediately execute a command on a remote machine? Or do you have strict network security policies?

Comment: Actually I don't have access to remote server due to security policies. That's why someone else excute the script and find that it's not working. The main issue is that Get ChildItem not able to find any file on given location.

Comment: In this case, the most likely mistake is the wrong path.

Comment: We cross checked path multiple times but didn't find any error.Is there any constraints on cmdlet "Get-Childitem" for older PowerShell version ???

Comment: This is hardly the case. As far as I know, this command behaves the same in versions, starting with powershell 2. How about permissions to the desired folder?

Comment: How to check permission?? We can browse the files using explorer.I'm new to PowerShell.